# Creating a feedback RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I will propose a trivial example to explain my question. So yes, there are many techniques I could use in post processing etc. but I would like the model to have the following ability.

Say I have the input:

`today i went to the shop`

that is fed in letter by letter to an RNN type model. The output is the probability that a letter belongs to the word `went`. But here's the thing, I want the output to be:

`today i went to the shop`
`000000001111000000000000`

At index 8 (`w`), a regular RNN would say the probability that character belongs to the word `went` is say, `0.2`. However, after the RNN has been fed the letter `e`, which would be given a probability of say, `0.3`, the probability of `w` belonging to `went` would actually increase since the subsequent letter also has a likelhiood of belonging to `went`. Essentially, I would like the model to "feedback" new information to previous characters/outputs to update previous outputs.